# Printing 2x2 matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I write a program to print a **2x2 matrix** where the digits represented in each matrix is given through user input.

For instance:

```
userin = 1 2     #two digit input with a spacing in between
userin2 = 3 4    #userin and userin2 is first matrix
userin3 = 5 6
userin4 = 7 8    #userin3 and userin4 is second matrix

The program would then print out: [[1,2],[3,4]],   #first matrix
                                  [[5,6],[7,8]]    #second matrix
```

I got the program to work as I want but i feel that the code I wrote is so inefficient that I'm creating too many empty list to cater for the user input.

```
userin = input("Enter first two digit for first 2x2 matrix: ").split(' ')
userin2 = input("Enter last two digit for first 2x2 matrix: ").split(' ')
userin3 = input("Enter first two digit for second 2x2 matrix: ").split(' ')
userin4 = input("Enter last two digit for second 2x2 matrix: ").split(' ')
lst1 = []
lst2 = []
lst3 = []
lst4 = []
matrix = []
matrix2 = []

for x in userin:
    x = int(x)
    lst1.append(x)

for j in userin2:
    j = int(j)
    lst2.append(j)

for x in userin3:
    x = int(x)
    lst3.append(x)

for j in userin4:
    j = int(j)
    lst4.append(j)

matrix.append(lst1)
matrix.append(lst2)
matrix2.append(lst3)
matrix2.append(lst4)
print(matrix)
print(matrix2)
```

The program outputs in the format I want which is *[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]* but I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this.

**Note that I'm not advised to use numpy and other built in library.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is better suited for code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: look up list comprehesion and note that string.split returns a list

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple examples of alternate ways. I'm not sure the first example is what you are looking for but I threw it in for fun!

```
>>> userin = '1 2'.split()
... userin2 = '3 4'.split()
... userin3 = '5 6'.split()
... userin4 = '7 8'.split()
>>> print('[[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]'.format(*userin, *userin2))
... print('[[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]'.format(*userin3, *userin4))
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
>>> print([[int(a) for a in pair] for pair in (userin, userin2)])
... print([[int(a) for a in pair] for pair in (userin3, userin4)])
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
# make a list of lists with the input
userin = [[input("Enter first two digit for first 2x2 matrix: ").strip().split(' '),
                 input("Enter last two digit for first 2x2 matrix: ").strip().split(' ')],
          [input("Enter first two digit for second 2x2 matrix: ").strip().split(' '),
                 input("Enter last two digit for second 2x2 matrix: ").strip().split(' ')]]

for matrix in userin: # loop through inner lists
    for index, row in enumerate(matrix): # loop through each matrix
        matrix[index] = [int(item) for item in row] # convert input to integers

print(",\n".join(str(matrix) for matrix in userin)) # print
```

If its always going to be just those 4 input statements, I think this is fine. If the input is variable, making a function would make more sense.

Output:

```
Enter first two digit for first 2x2 matrix: 1 2
Enter last two digit for first 2x2 matrix: 3 4
Enter first two digit for second 2x2 matrix: 5 6
Enter last two digit for second 2x2 matrix: 7 8
[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Why not just let the `ValueError` raise on its own? How is your custom message any clearer than this, `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put in while loop to get arbitrary number of matrices and why not take in all 4 elements at once?

Something like:

```
user_in = ['0']
matrices = []
while (user_in[0].lower() != 'q'):
   user_in = input("Input 2x2 matrix(space separated), enter 'q' to quit: ").split(' ')
   if len(user_in) == 4:
      a, b, c, d = user_in
      m2x2 = [[int(a), int(b)], [int(c), int(d)]]
      matrices.append(m2x2)

for matrix in matrices:
    print(matrix)
```

Comment: [When a string contains single or double quote characters, however, use the other one to avoid backslashes in the string. It improves readability.](http://pep8.org/#string-quotes)